# Unable to insert row into table using an Oracle Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to know what's the problem, or your advice to connect to Oracle. I'm trying with this but when I try to insert values, it doesn't work.

I'm using the Visual Web Developer 2008 and when I add a database on Database Explorer connections, it's working. But when I try to connect via this connection string, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

I don't get an exception, so apparently it's working well. But this code apparently doesn't insert! The `id` column is a `varchar(45)`. I created the table "test" just for testing purposes.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
    //string oradb = "Data Source=localhost;User ID=root;Password=jesua;Unicode=True;";
    String oracle = "User ID=root;Password=jesua;Unicode=True;Data Source=localhost;";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

    public void Conectar() {
        try 
        {
            con.Close();
            con.ConnectionString = oracle;                 
            con.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new Exception("No Conecto " + ex);
        }  
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        // con.ConnectionString = oracle;
        con.Close();
    }

    public void agregar() {
        this.Conectar();
        OracleCommand query = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO testing (id) VALUES ('testing')");
        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        desconectar();           
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            agregar();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Console.Write("No agrego " + ex);
        }
        TextBox1.Text = "Conected";
    }
}
```

--------------------------UPDATE------------------

So,

i found the way to do that,

i hope anyone here can use this code in a future...

This code creates the connection betwen Oracle and asp.net C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; // ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace proyecto
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void dbconnect() {
        string oradb = "Data Source=localhost;User ID={Yoir ID};Password={Your Password};";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); // C#
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TESTING(id) VALUES ('valor')"; 
        int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        if (rowsUpdated == 0) 
         Console.Write("Record not inserted"); 
        else 
        Console.Write("Success!"); 
        conn.Dispose(); 
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dbconnect();

    }
   }
 }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Why did you people vote my post down? pff... i'm just asking my problem...

Comment: @GrantWinney Thank you, well, on console doesn't shows me anything, apparently it's working well. But this code apparently doesn't insert!,

Comment: @GrantWinney yeah it's a varchar(45), i created the table test just for testing proposes

Answer (score 0):

The connection string that works for me is

```
connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522))  
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=system;Password=pass;"  
providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

It seems that you are missing the **Service Name** and **Provider Name**. You can find the *service name* in **tnsnames.ora** file which will be in your installation directory. Also make sure you have installed **ODP.NET** for *Oracle 11g* correctly, added reference to the *Oracle.DataAccess.dll* into your project and add the *Provider Name* in the connection string.